# Icon@2x.PNG Even though it isn't? Can't submit Apps to iTunes Connect

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, app-store-connect, organizer

Trying to upload my app, the app sends fine but I get this error via email once the binary has been sent.

'Dear developer,

We have discovered one or more issues with your recent binary submission for "MyApp". Before your app can be reviewed, the following issues must be corrected:

Corrupt PNG File - The PNG icon file Icon@2x.png appears to be corrupt.

Once these issues have been corrected , go to the Version Details page and click Ready to Upload Binary. Continue through the submission process until the app status is Waiting for Upload and then use Application Loader to upload the corrected binary.

Regards,

The App Store team'

I've tried replaced the Icon@2x.png and re-submitted but I got the same email

Comment: Can you post these icon files in the question (or a link to them) in your question so we can see what you're talking about?

Answer (score 21):

This is a problem with Xcode 4.3.1. The solution is to disable PNG compression.

1. Project > target > Build Settings > Show All > first item under the Packaging header

   - *I searched for "pack"*
2. Toggle **Compress PNG Files** to **NO**

[image]

While you're at it, go dup [rdar://11046386](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=1597406) and [rdar://11035448](http://openradar.appspot.com/11035448) on [Apple's Bug Reporter](https://bugreport.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/RadarWeb.woa/wa/signIn)

Further discussion on the [Apple Dev Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/630749#630749)

Comment: This will work — unless, of course, you need to enable PNG compression because of app bundle size concerns. There's another solution I found: make sure that if you export your icons with Photoshop's Save for Web, do NOT check Interlaced. Then you should be able to submit AND leave PNG compression enabled. See more at the StackOverflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10860096/1078579

Comment: Another option is to change the file type on just the icon files from 'Default - PNG Image' to 'Icon'.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error again and again, I couldn't upload my App because of a corrupted PNG.

I though it was because I failed to uncheck the transparency box when exporting the PNG in Photoshop (which you should/must do) but it appears that there was a layer in my Photoshop image that caused the problem and corrupted my file when exporting in PNG. If ever you think of "save as" and then specify PNG format in your Photoshop, it will not solve the problem either.

You must remake this buggy layer and export your image again. As Domsou said before you can use [ImageOptim](http://imageoptim.com) to verify that your new PNG is not corrupt... and optimize its size at the same time  (Actually it does not check it but if the file is corrupted it won't be able to optimize it). I've done what I just said and now my App is waiting for review :) Good luck (hope your image does not have 30 layers...mine had 2)

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure your image covers all the [requirements](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html)?

Comment: How do you create/convert/resize the file? What are you using (imagemagick, photoshop, ...?)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem in the info.plist file !!!!
When removing icons from the app, on record is keeping in place.

I removed it from those 2 nodes :
 - Icon Files
 - Icon files (IOS 5)

i don't know again if that worked but i didn't received mails for this moment...

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me :

Click on those 4 images :
 - the icon
 - the icon@2x
 - the default
 - the default@2x

in the right window 'Identity and Type' select this File Type : 'Icon'

Answer (score 0):

If you Build application for Archiving you'll probably see the warning saying you have mismatched icon settings.
I've got this error when i've submitted app using xCode 4.3 with deploy target set to iOS 3.0.
My app bundle had Icon.png and Icon@2x.png, after i've added new icons they were named Icon57.png & Icon114.png, old ones were not deleted automatically.

This is how i've solved this problem:
1) removed old Icon.png & Icon@2x.png from project;
2) new Icon57.png & Icon114.png renamed to Icon.png & Icon@2x.png
3) in *-info.plist i've corrected icon records from Icon57.png & Icon114.png to Icon.png & Icon@2x.png
4) Added CFBundleIconFile row with value Icon.png

That's it! =)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an icon today. The icon was saved as an interlaced PNG.  I re-saved it as non-interlaced, resubmitted and it wasn't rejected.

Answer (score 0):

That works for me, too. Just change icon72.png and icon144.png file type to "Icon", then App Store accept the submission.

Answer (score 0):

@Phatblat's solution will work, but it doesn't fix the root of the problem. The primary cause is probably that "Interlaced" was enabled when exporting the app icons from Photoshop. Disabling PNG compression will prevent the rejection, but it will often increase the size of your IPA. If you disable Interlacing and resave all of your icons in Photoshop, you can re-enable PNG compression and should be able to submit your app without issue.

This is what happened to me with my app Pillboxie, which as tons of images. I needed PNG compression to keep my file size low.