# iTunes Connect sends email about a issue with icon file, how to fix?

Tags: objective-c, ios, app-store-connect

This is the email:

*Dear developer,
We have discovered one or more issues with your recent binary submission for "Bla". Before your app can be reviewed, the following issues must be corrected:
Corrupt Icon File - The icon file 72 x 72.png appears to be corrupt.
Once these issues have been corrected , go to the Version Details page and click Ready to Upload Binary. Continue through the submission process until the app status is Waiting for Upload and then use Application Loader to upload the corrected binary.*

I have change the file and re-upload the app, but I got the email again.

Comment: Make sure "compress png's" is turned off in the build settings.

Answer (score 3):

Can you open the file in Preview, and choose 'Tools' -> 'Show Inspector'?  The file may be using some PNG format features that Apple don't like.  They want RGB, 8 bit depth, no alpha.  See the [Custom Icon and Image Creation Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW2).

For comparison, here are screenshots of the Preview Inspector, showing properties of an icon for an app that was accepted.  If you're unsure, post similar screenshots for the properties of your picture.

[image: Preview Inspector for PNG, showing the General tab]

[image: Preview Inspector for PNG, showing the PNG tab]

The "Pixels Per Meter" part may or may not appear.  It wasn't there when I first opened some icon files five minutes ago, and now it appears for every PNG I open.  Weird.

**Edit**: also check the icon entries in your 'Info.plist', or the 'Info' tab for your Target.  (These are *not* the same thing, as I just spent several hours discovering.  Settings in the 'Info' tab override your 'Info.plist'.)  As of the iOS 5.1 SDK, these include **Icon file** (a string), **Icon files** (an array), and **Icon files (iOS 5)** (a dictionary containing at least one dictionary containing an array).  XCode seems to add your launch images to this list too.  Don't rely on it to keep the list tidy - I have sometimes found outdated filenames in mine.

For further comparison, here's what ended up in the Info.plist of a valid app.  Your filenames may be different, as long as they match the resources in your project.

[image: XCode Info.plist icons entries]

Comment: But this is the second time I upload the app, and the first time, the icon file was ok, just now with a update that I want to upload there's the problem.

Comment: I've changed the file for the icon, with new one with the specifications and the problem turns to 114x114 icon file, wich I´ve changed by new one, and then the problem turn back to the icon file 72x72

Comment: @Evaristoyok: There may also be a problem file referenced by your Info.plist.  I've edited my answer with some thoughts on this.

Comment: It's funny how Apple sticks the default images in the icon files .. understandable if there are no actual icons (then it will show the splash screen scaled down as the icon) .. but I think 14 entries in the icon Files is a bit overkill.

Answer (score 3):

As Michael Dautermanm says.

Make sure "compress png's" is turned off in the build settings.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm the developer of the app Pillboxie. I have been having the same issue as you, but I believe I may have finally found a solution.

Before proceeding with my suggestion, make sure that your Info.plist and all icon filenames appear *exactly* as Apple requires. Keep checking the documentation to make sure you're up-to-date, but Dondragmer's recommendation looks correct to me.

I created all my image resources, including app icons, in Photoshop, exporting for web as PNG-24's. Because Pillboxie has numerous images, setting "Compress png's" to YES in the build settings helps me save several megabytes of space. I was getting the same error as you until I tried turning off this compression, as Evaristoyok suggests. However, my app jumped up several mb. I hoped to find a better way.

Tonight I found the following link: [article](http://www.iphoneappdevelopment.hk/error-message-corrupt-icon-file-the-icon-file-appears-to-be-corrupt/). In it the author suggests to make sure that "Interlaced" is NOT selected in Photoshop when exporting images in the Save For Web & Devices dialog window. I re-exported all icon and launch images with this disabled, and it solved my issue. I was able to submit my app *and* still leave png compression enabled.

Comment: More details on how I save my Photoshop images:  //  Filetype: PNG-24
  //  Transparency: YES  //  Interlaced: NO  //  Convert to sRGB: NO  //  Matte: None  //  Quality: Bicubic  //  Metadata: None  //